# Android JsonWriter disconnecting clients from server socket

Tags: android

I have developed sample Android app for **Socket** communication over WiFi, with multiple clients. I am using **JsonWriter** for writing messages and **JsonReader** for reading messages.

When communicating one-to-one is no issue, but one-to-many is having some issues.

**For Example:**

My server S1 is connected with Client C1,C2 and C3, when the server try to send messages to all client at a same time the client C3 only receiving the messages but not others.

**ServerSocketClass**

```
public class ServiceMain extends Service implements OnResponseJsonWriter {
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private MyThread myThread;
    static final int SocketServerPORT = 8080;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;
    static List<ChatClient> userList;
    static String msgLog = "";
    private String TAG = ServiceMain.class.getSimpleName();
    private boolean isServerAction = false;
    private String TOKEN_REQUEST;
    private Context mContext;
    private JsonWriter writer = null;
    private JSON_Writer jsonWriter;

    private DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    private DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
                      mContext = ServiceMain.this;
        userList = new ArrayList<ChatClient>();
        myThread = new MyThread();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public synchronized void onDestroy() {
        try {
            if (isRunning) {
                myThread.interrupt();
                myThread.stop();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {

        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
               if (!isRunning) {
                      myThread.start();
            isRunning = true;
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onJsonWriterRespnse(boolean isSuccess) {

        try {
            writer.flush();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onJsonWriterRespnse " + e);
        }
    }


    class MyThread extends Thread {
        static final long DELAY = 3000;

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while (isRunning) {
                try {

                    ChatServerThread chatServerThread = new ChatServerThread();
                    chatServerThread.start();
                    Thread.sleep(DELAY);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    isRunning = false;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class ChatServerThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Socket socket = null;
            try {

                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);

                while (true) {
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
                    userList.add(client);
                    ConnectThread connectThread = new ConnectThread(client, socket);
                    connectThread.start();
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

            } finally {


                if (socket != null) {
                    try {

                        socket.close();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class ChatClient {
        String id;
        Socket socket;
        ConnectThread chatThread;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
        }
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {

        Socket socket;
        ChatClient connectClient;
        String msgToSend = "";

        ConnectThread(ChatClient client, Socket socket) {
            connectClient = client;
            this.socket = socket;
            client.socket = socket;
            client.chatThread = this;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {


            try {
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                String n = dataInputStream.readUTF();
                connectClient.id = n;
                socketConnectionResponse(connectClient, connectClient.id);

                while (true) {
                    if (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
                    }

                    isServerAction = false;
                    if (!msgToSend.equals("")) {
                        TeacherAttention attentionModel;
                        switch (msgToSend) {
                            case Constants.LOOK_AT_ME:
                                isServerAction = true;
                                TOKEN_REQUEST = Constants.LOOK_AT_ME;
                                msgToSend = "";
                                attentionModel = new TeacherAttention(Constants.TEACHER_ATTENTION_REQUEST,
                                        Constants.RESPONSE_SUCCESS, Constants.LOOK_AT_ME);
                                writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(dataOutputStream, "UTF-8"));
                                writer.setIndent(" ");
                                // for write JSON
                                jsonWriter = new JSON_Writer(mContext, writer, attentionModel, "");

                                break;
                        }
                    }

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (dataInputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataInputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                Log.e("TAG", "finally??");
                userList.remove(connectClient);


            }

        }

        private void sendMsg(String msg) {
            msgToSend = msg;
        }
    }

    public static void broadcastMsgToAll(String msg) {
               for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
            userList.get(i).chatThread.sendMsg(msg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * send response to single user
     *
     * @param client
     * @param userid
     */
    public void socketConnectionResponse(ChatClient client, String userid) {

        if (client != null) {
            client.chatThread.sendMsg(userid);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ServiceMain.this, "No user connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**ClientSocketClass:**

```
public class ClientSocketService extends Service implements OnResponseJsonWriter,
        OnResponseJsonReader {
    private static String TAG = ClientSocketService.class.getSimpleName();

    static final int socketServerPORT = 8080;
    private ChatClientThread chatClientThread = null;

    static String msgToSend = "";
    static boolean goOut = false, isSocketRunning = false;

    private JsonReader reader;

    private Context mContext;

    private DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    private DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    private JsonWriter writer = null;

    private JSON_Reader jsonReader;
    private JSON_Writer jsonWriter;

    public static Socket socket = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        getAllStudent = new ArrayList<>();
        mContext = ClientSocketService.this;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        chatClientThread = new ChatClientThread(getUserID(), getTeacherIP(), socketServerPORT);
        chatClientThread.start();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    private class ChatClientThread extends Thread {
        String name;
        String dstAddress;
        int dstPort;

        ChatClientThread(String name, String address, int port) {
            this.name = name;
            dstAddress = address;
            dstPort = port;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF(name);
                dataOutputStream.flush();

                while (!goOut) {
                    if (dataInputStream.available() > 0) {
                        reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(dataInputStream, "UTF-8"));
                        try {
                            jsonReader = new JSON_Reader(mContext, reader);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "dataInputStream" + e);
                        } finally {
                        }

                    }

                                   }
                    isSocketRunning = true;
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                final String eString = e.toString();
                Log.e("eString 1", "eString " + eString);
                isSocketRunning = false;

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                final String eString = e.toString();
                Log.e("eString 2", "eString " + eString);
                isSocketRunning = false;


            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        isSocketRunning = false;
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (dataOutputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataOutputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (dataInputStream != null) {
                    try {
                        dataInputStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static void sendMsg(String msg) {
        msgToSend = msg;
    }

    private void disconnect() {
        goOut = true;
    }

    public static boolean isSocketRunning() {

        return isSocketRunning;
    }



    @Override
    public void onJsonWriterRespnse(boolean isSuccess) {
        try {
            writer.flush();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onJsonWriterRespnse " + e);
            isSocketRunning = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSocketReaderResponse(String requestToken, final ArrayList<SocketResponseModel> socketResponse) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSocketResponseUpdateIP(SocketResponseUpdateIp responsIp) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTeacherAttention(TeacherAttention teacherAttention) {
        Intent lookIntent;
        switch (teacherAttention.getTokenStatus()) {
            case Constants.LOOK_AT_ME:
                lookIntent = new Intent(this, LookAtMeActivity.class);
                lookIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(lookIntent);
                break;
                    }

}
```

Comment: `when the server try to send messages to all client at a same time the client C3 only receiving the messages but not others. But in this case I am using normal DataInputStream and DataOutputStream it's working perfectly.`. Sorry but i do not understand this confusing message. You contradict yourself. Please edit your post.

Comment: It is strange that there is nothing about the problem mentioned in the subject in your post.